# Como fazer is_unique de dois campos?

Tags: php, codeigniter, callback, restrição-único

Estou com uma necessidade que não sei como realizar.

Bom, o meu problema:

Tenho um campo **is_unique** que se refere a dois campos do meu BD, o IDENTIFICADOR e a PLANTA.
Gostaria de saber como realizar essa validação?

para um único campo eu utilizo assim:

```
$imeiRules = "required|min_length[3]|max_length[45]|xss_clean|strip_tags";
        if($this->input->post('txtImei') != $this->input->post('imeiOld')){
            $imeiRules .= " |is_unique[equipamento.equipamento_imei]";
        }
```

só não sei fazer com doi campos unicos.

Comment: Já tentou fazer `"|is_unique[campo1]|is_unique[campo2]"` ?

Comment: Pior que já... e nada.

Comment: Veja essa resposta http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575165/validation-unique-field-in-codeigniter-with-2-index

Comment: Obrigado, agora consegui entender como realizar a validação.

Answer (score 1):

### Deixarei traduzido o [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14577385/2556111) que o @Wallace Masters informou acima para quem não sabe inglês.

"Eu não acho que o CI tenha uma solução interna para caso com mais de uma Chave Primaria. Eu usaria um callback_ como este:

Mas perceba que você precisa enviar a segunda chave primária como uma uma informação extra e a regra precisa ser aplicada na primeira chave primária.

Pesquise na documentação por callbacks para saber mais."

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('form_field', 'form_label', 'callback_combpk[$pk2]');
    public function combpk($pk1, $pk2)
        {
               $this->db->where('field1', $pk1);
               $this->db->where('field2', $pk2);
               $result = $this->db->get('table');
               if($result->num_rows() > 0)
               {
                  $this->form_validation->set_message('combpk','something'); // set your message
                  return false;
               }
               else{ return true;}

        }
```

---

Adição minha:

[Callbacks - Usando sua própria validação ( CI 3.0 )](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html?highlight=form%20validation#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods)